# How can I store variables in traits so that it can be used in other methods on trait?

Tags: rust

I have several objects in my code that have common functionality.  These objects act essentially like services where they have a life-time (controlled by start/stop) and perform work until their life-time ends.  I am in the process of trying to refactor my code to reduce duplication but getting stuck.

At a high level, my objects all have the code below implemented in them.

```
impl SomeObject {
    fn start(&self) {
        // starts a new thread.
        // stores the 'JoinHandle' so thread can be joined later.
    }

    fn do_work(&self) {
        // perform work in the context of the new thread.
    }

    fn stop(&self) {
        // interrupts the work that this object is doing.
        // stops the thread.
    }
}
```

Essentially, these objects act like "services" so in order to refactor, my first thought was that I should create a trait called "service" as shown below.

```
trait Service {
    fn start(&self) {}

    fn do_work(&self);

    fn stop(&self) {}      
}
```

Then, I can just update my objects to each implement the "Service" trait.  The issue that I am having though, is that since traits are not allowed to have fields/properties, I am not sure how I can go about saving the 'JoinHandle' in the trait so that I can use it in the other methods.

Is there an idiomatic way to handle this problem in Rust?

tldr; how can I save variables in a trait so that they can be re-used in different trait methods?

Edit:

Here is the solution I settled on.  Any feedback is appreciated.

```
extern crate log;

use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

pub struct Context {
    name: String,
    thread_join_handle: JoinHandle<()>,
    is_thread_running: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

pub trait Service {
    fn start(&self, name: String) -> Context {
        log::trace!("starting service, name=[{}]", name);
        let is_thread_running = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));
        let cloned_is_thread_running = is_thread_running.clone();
        let thread_join_handle = std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
            while cloned_is_thread_running.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                Self::do_work();
            }
        });
        log::trace!("started service, name=[{}]", name);
        return Context {
            name: name,
            thread_join_handle: thread_join_handle,
            is_thread_running: is_thread_running,
        };
    }

    fn stop(context: Context) {
        log::trace!("stopping service, name=[{}]", context.name);
        context.is_thread_running.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
        context
            .thread_join_handle
            .join()
            .expect("joining service thread");
        log::trace!("stopped service, name=[{}]", context.name);
    }

    fn do_work();
}
```

Comment: *"traits are not allowed to have fields/properties"* - but implementors of the trait can

Comment: Does anyone know of any crates that exist that already does this?  I basically am looking for a way to create local (same process) services that can be started/stopped and communicate with each other possibly with channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to save your JoinHandle in the struct's state itself, then the other methods can access it as well because they all get all the struct's data passed to them already.

```rust
struct SomeObject {
  join_handle: JoinHandle;
}

impl Service for SomeObject {
  fn start(&mut self) {
      // starts a new thread.
      // stores the 'JoinHandle' so thread can be joined later.
      self.join_handle = what_ever_you_wanted_to_set //Store it here like this
  }

  fn do_work(&self) {
      // perform work in the context of the new thread.
  }

  fn stop(&self) {
      // interrupts the work that this object is doing.
      // stops the thread.
  }
}
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was hoping to somehow reduce the code though.  If I understand the suggestion correctly, all the implementations would need to include the "join_handle" and implementations for "start" and "stop".  This means I would have a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Yes, all of your Services will need a join_handel field luckily that isn't very much code. As for the other piece about having to implement the same thing over and over again you're in luck because rust traits support default implementations. So when you define your trait you can write each method with a default implementation of it and any struct that implements that trait will automatically be able to use that default implementation. If that doesn't make sense the rust book goes into more detail with traits here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html

Comment: Oh I see.  I think I understand.  So the trait would have a method called "get_join_handle" and "set_join_handle"? In the default implementation for "start" and "stop", I would just make reference to the "join_handle" methods?  Then, each of my implementations would have a JoinHandle defined in their struct and would implement "get_join_handle" and "set_join_handle"?

Comment: You don't actually need those getters and setters since each of those methods in the trait actually are passed self which means they will already have all the structs data so you have no need to write getters and setters. If you want to change the data just make sure you're passing a mutable reference to self.

Comment: "You don't actually need those getters and setters"
To access the Services join_handle from the trait you must implement the setters and getters. This is also how it is explained in the linked documentation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html in the trait Animal.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're using the trait, you could restructure your code and make it so start returns a JoinHandle and the other functions take the join handle as input

```
trait Service {
    fn start(&self) -> JoinHandle;

    fn do_work(&self, handle: &mut JoinHandle);

    fn stop(&self, handle: JoinHandle);
}
```

(maybe with different function arguments depending on what you need). this way you could probably cut down on duplicate code by putting all the code that handles the handles (haha) outside of the structs themselves and makes it more generic. If you want the structs the use the JoinHandle outside of this trait, I'd say it's best to just do what Equinox suggested and just make it a field.